# Append tables by columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have to generate a report that append tables by columns in MySQL. I have to append 10 tables that are format as:

```
id   |   name   |   month   
---------------------------------
 5    |   john    |     1
 7    |   mike    |     1
 8    |   jane    |     0
```

The ouput shoul be like:

```
id  |   name | month 1 | month 2 | month 3 |........| month 10|
------------------------------------------------------------------
5   |   john |     1   |     0   |   bla   | ........|     1   |
7   |   mike |     1   |     0   |   bla   | ........|     1   |
8   |   jane |     0   |     0   |   bla   | ........|     1   |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dare we ask why you have 10 tables

Comment: Actually I have one table with months identified by number. However, I could only be able to get 10 tables out of the this one doing some joins and selects. I was thinking about 'join them by columns' now. Any other suggestion?

Comment: So I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: month1 m1 Inner JOIN month2 m2 ON m1.id = m2.id   but i am failing to see the buigger picture